# SSL Security Error : Source MS Ole DB provider for SQL server

Tags: c++

I have an application that was needed to be brought up to TLS 1.2.    this is a c++ app.   In order to bring it up to compliance I changed to provider to MSOLEDB and made the application use the MS Ole DB drivers 18.3.
Worked great in lower envionrments.   However took it to production today  and I am getting this lovel error:

i don't get it ...but what am I missing here.

I have tried to ensure that the ciphers are correct, ensured the TLS registry settings are correct and ensured strong crypto registry settings are correct as per this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server

Comment: Start with the [tour] and read [ask]. For a proper programming question, consider including a [mcve] as well.

Comment: The error message seems to be missing?